# Libgdx - ram usage

Tags: android, libgdx

I have 88 textures (but at ANY moment only 53 are loaded into asset manager).
From 53 around 40 are of average size 250 x 250. The other 13 are around 500 x 500.

So if I do the calculation 250 x 250 x 4 x 40 = 10mb + 500 x 500 x 4 x 13 = 13mb ==> 23mb + some ram used for game running = about 30mb, if I am correct. But I am on 50mb of ram usage.

I also have 4 sounds, in total everything takes 3.57mb of space, of course the png format doesn't matter.

But is it normal that 53 (250 x 250) pictures take up 50mb of ram? Because I see alot of game, which look alot larger than mine, and take alot less ram. Any ideas of the cause?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on some of your details, but since you're using Android, this means you're using Java. Java objects contain more information than just the data you care about, and objects that may've gone out of scope may still be held by the JVM for some time, especially if there's a valid reference hidden somewhere that won't let an object get garbage-collected, etc. Just a guess, since there's no code here or anything, etc.

Comment: But it seems as my objects take a minimum amount of space, because 2 hours ago I disposed and created a new screen each time I changed screen. Now I keep reference to all 4 screens, so everything is already made, and the ram usage is almost exactly the same or better said is the same!

Comment: "It seems" can be misleading. Unfortunately, there's not enough data in the post for others to evaluate the situation more objectively (e.g. code, results from a profiler, etc). I think you need to improve your post. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more help.

Comment: Also, textures are GPU resources, you can't just look at CPU ram for that. And if you do look at VRAM then you'll see that the storage is most likely POT aligned (e.g. 250 becomes 256, etc.). Apart from that, your approach is very inefficient, have a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer those 53 images probably all fit in 1 or 2 textures.

Comment: This game runs smoothly, but ye I am gonna use texture packer in the future. I am talking about the RAM when you open the task manager on an android phone. Because color switch which seems an alot bigger game than mine, is using the same amound of CPU ram. And you are saying that if I use 250 x 250 or 256 x 256 I use the same amount of RAM?

Comment: No, I am saying that the amount of RAM is not related to your textures.